# This pointer implementation

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
public:
    void Test()
    {
      AfxMessageBox("Test Function");
    }
};

A* obj= new A();
delete obj;
obj= NULL;
obj->Test();
```

Here Test function called without any error, I am using Visual studio compiler.
if member function not accessing any other member in a class, "this" pointer will not use 
at all? is this applicable for all compilers?

Comment: Although it's not documented anywhere (that I know of), the Microsoft compilers will let you get away with this. More than that, some of Microsoft's own library code (eg MFC's `CWnd::GetSafeHwnd()`) makes use of this "feature". Still better not to use it.

Answer (score 10):

This is undefined behavior. It may work, it may not work, it may cause other weird bugs.

## Don't rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: We can  say undefined behavior, , but if this is working all the time without any error or crash, there should be some trick right?? that is what my doubt..